# Application to Application authentication/access control without HTTPS

Tags: security, authentication, hash, cryptography

On the current project I'm working on, we have the following problem.

Our software is a Location Based Services platform and applications can connect and use our services through our exposed webservices using SOAP. Until now our platform was only used by internal applications, but now we would like to open it for third party applications. For that we need an authentication mechanism.

Because of our customers' infrastructure and load balancing solution, we cannot use HTTPS. The original idea was that applications can just use HTTPS and send the password we authenticate.

A solution would be the next:
The application has the password. The application generates a random string (salt) and creates a hash. Then the application creates an HTTP request sending the hash, the salt and a timestamp. This three is enough for us to authenticate, as we can generate the same hash and compare.

My problem is that for this we need to store the password in our database in clear text, because we need to do the same process using the given salt so we can compare the result and authenticate the application. Storing passwords in clear text is unacceptable.

Do you know about any authentication/access control mechanism that would fit this situation? Generally, do you know about any good books/sources about application authentication/access control mechanisms?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application (client) can **hash the password two times**. Note that the server should generate the other random salt, not the client! Otherwise the attacker can log with this hash also. You can also **make it safer** by storing password specific salt in the database.

The protocol:

0) servers retrieves `salt` for that particular password from database, generates salt2, and sends both to the client

1) client sends `hash(hash(password, salt), salt2, timestamp)` and `timestamp`.

2) server retrieves `hash(password, salt)` from the database and compares.

Note that if you are on the network where attackers can **not only sniff, but also modify the traffic**, as [Paulo pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742229/application-to-application-authentication-access-control-without-https/7743470#7743470), you should **sign EVERY message**: `hash(hash(password, salt), salt2, timestamp, message)` and check it at server. (E.g. for the case when the attacker could modify the message to contain delete command...)

Note that there is still a **problem when user needs to SET/CHANGE the password safely**. You cannot do it safely with just hash function over unsafe network, you need some kind of cipher/decipher.

Also note that **the slower the hash function is, the safer** (because of the dictionary attack). If you don't have access to special slow hash function, you may also call normal fast hash function 100000 times.

Comment: @Aston: Just a note: Use a slow hash function here (at least for the hash in the database, but maybe also for the outer hash), so attackers which get the hashes from the DB can't easily brute-force the passwords. Thus use scrypt, bcrypt or PBKDF2 (with suitable work factors), and not simply a fast hash like SHA-1, SHA-2 (or even SHA-3, when it will be ready).

Comment: @Aston, or, maybe even more safer, the salt2 should be generated randomly by the server and sent to client. Also, note that the slower the hash function is, the safer (because of the dictionary attack).

Comment: @Paulo, aah, we just cross-talked :-).

Comment: Yeah the more time you spend on hashing the better it will be, makes sense.

A note on your note: set/change password is fine, we use our internal webapp that has HTTPS for that.

Comment: This is no better than storing the plaintext password: Any attacker who obtains the hash can use it just as they would the password without this extra layer of hashing.

Comment: Also, what you're trying to do in part 2 is called an HMAC; you should use that construction rather than inventing your own.

Comment: @NickJohnson: *"Any attacker who obtains the hash can use it just as they would the password"* - that's not correct, because the hash must be done using salt2 sent by the server! Read the protocol again! But thanks for HMAC.

Comment: @Thomas Any attacker who obtains the first/inner hash can use it in place of the password. There is absolutely no point in both ends hashing the password in this protocol.

Comment: @NickJohnson, the attacker cannot obtain the first/inner hash from network traffic. He can if he cracks the database. I doubt you can achieve anything better with just one-direction hashes (without decryption).

Comment: @TomasT Yes - but presumably making things harder for someone who compromises the database was exactly your goal in hashing the password - why else would you do it? - and I'm pointing out that it adds absolutely nothing to the security of the scheme.

Comment: [Hashing Security](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) - good tutorial to read about hashing

Answer (score 2):

Instead of inventing your own solution, you should use an established one. SOAP has support for cryptographic authentication such as WS-Security - see Craig Forster's comment on this answer for suggestions.

The best choice in other cases is usually [oauth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oauth); it provides both authorization and authentication, and deals with a lot of cryptographic issues that you're not likely to spot when building your own.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment, but not the proposed solution.  SOAP-based web services should use WS-Security, most likely with a combination of SAML tokens for authentication and XML signatures and encryption for message-level security.

Comment: @craigforster Somehow I missed that the OP was using SOAP. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using an authentication solution which does not contain an integrity check of the whole message (or stream) is insecure.

While the hashing solution originally proposed by Thomas T. (`hash(hash(password, salt), salt2, timestamp)`, where `hash(password, salt)` is stored in the database, and `salt2` is newly generated) makes sure than an attacker can't get the password (or any data which will be useful for logging in after the timestamp expires), it alone does not prevent an active attacker to hijack the session after the authentication, and send any SOAP requests wanted (and intercept the responses).

What would be needed here is some way to make sure that no data is changed. This is known as a message authentication code (MAC). The usual definition of a MAC includes some (shared secret) key and the message as input, and an authentication token as output.

The usual way to use this would be to do some authenticated key exchange at the beginning of the communication (using either a shared secret or some known public key), and then use a part of the now shared secret as the MAC key, which is then used to authenticate following messages.
(Doing this then essentially is a reinvention of SSL/TLS (or parts thereof), potentially doing the same mistakes again.)

If you have only one message to send, you can instead use the MAC as a kind of symmetric signature, using the password hash (salted and generated with a slow hash function) as a MAC key.

Another way to view this would be to take the message to authenticate as an input to the outer hash in Thomas T's authentication scheme. (Make sure to authenticate everything that is worth authenticating.)

Comment: Good note, @Paulo. Yes, if the attacker can not only sniff, but also modify the network traffic, it's little bit more complicated (however, this kind of attack is not so common). I think your last paragraph (hash the whole message in my outer hash function) is the solution wanted.

Comment: however, if you don't do that, the security of authentication itself would not be broken. But it is good if you need to protect the other client-server communication against any modification, which is a different thing (probably often neglected). E.g. the attacker could change the client messages to launch DELETE commands etc. Then you need to send signing hashes with every message. I updated my answer.